# Force Cart price calculation for configurable products

Tags: cart, configurable-product, price, quote

I have a custom module which adds multiple products to the cart. 
The user is then redirected to the listing page where she comes from.

In the header, the total price of the cart items is shown.
Problem is: this Price won't update!
If I add another product, the price of the product added **before** is added.
So the price shown is always the price before the last product(s) were added to the cart!

If I open the cart page, the correct price is shown!
How can I force magento to recalculate the price?

Answer (score 0):

You add the products too late.

You have to add the products before the `_collectTotals` is called on the `quote`

How do you add the products?